# Extending SQL Server query with extra table - very complicated query (to me at least)

Tags: sql-server, left-join

I'm creating a SQL query in SQL Server. I managed to get a fairly complicated SQL query working, but now I need to extend it by adding in a few extra tables, and I'm at a loss how to do it. I wrote the original query a year ago with lots and lots of trial and error (I'm not very proficient in SQL).

Let me explain what's going on in this query: it's an order picking database: the result query lists order lines that were not picked for whatever reason (no or insufficient stock, order picker chose not to, ...). These lines date from a point in the past (when the order # was closed by the order picker).

Now I want this report to highlight orderlines that can be picked at the moment the query is run. (reason: the order has not been shipped yet, so it may be possible to add here and there a few extra articles to that order => increased customer satisfaction).

So far, the query uses mainly the outgoingdetails table, because each record in this table points to an orderline that was or was not picked.

Now, I want to bring in 2 extra tables: the article table (so that I can display not only the orderline description in the query, but also the actual article number). the unique id of the article table is article.id, this field is used as the primary key in the outgoingdetails tabel (outgoingdetails.articleid), the real article number however is stored as article.externalnumber

The second table is ArticlesLocations. This contains the current stock levels per ArticleId (because the stock is stored per location, there may be several of the same articleid records in this table). Again, here the articleid is the key to use. I would need the sum of the field currentquantity grouped per articleid.

This will allow me to show each orderline (wether picked or not) together with the current stock level per orderline. In my report designer, I will then be able to highlight lines that were not picked at the time, but that have sufficient stock so we can pick them again.

I hope this makes sense to anyone here, I tried to be as precise as possible.

Here's the current query:

```sql
SELECT 
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliveryNumber AS ordernummer,
    Customer.CustomerName AS klantnaam,
    OutgoingDetails.OrderLineDescription AS artikel,
    MAX(OutgoingDetails.Quantity) AS gevraagd,
    SUM(ISNULL(OutgoingSerial.Quantity, 0)) AS gepickt,
    OutgoingDetails.LineNum AS lijnnummer,
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.distributeddate AS pickdatum
FROM
    (Customer
INNER JOIN
    (OutgoingSessionDelivery
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (OutgoingDetails
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (OutgoingLocation
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    OutgoingSerial ON OutgoingLocation.Id = OutgoingSerial.OutgoingLocationId)
    ON OutgoingDetails.Id = OutgoingLocation.OutgoingDetailsId)
    ON OutgoingSessionDelivery.Id = OutgoingDetails.SalesDeliveryId)
    ON Customer.Id = OutgoingSessionDelivery.CustomerId
    AND Customer.Id = OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliverToCustomerId)
-- WHERE OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliveryNumber = 12959 
--   AND OutgoingDetails.LineNum = 14
GROUP BY 
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliveryNumber,
    Customer.CustomerName,
    OutgoingDetails.OrderLineDescription,
    OutgoingDetails.LineNum,
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.distributeddate
HAVING 
    MAX(OutgoingDetails.Quantity) > SUM(ISNULL(OutgoingSerial.Quantity, 0));
```

Comment: Do you *really* need to nest those `ON` clauses? They make for quite a confusing and odd syntax. Though i admit I *do* use them from time to time, I normally at most nest 1, not 4. If I need more than 1 (and even often even if I do have 1) I use `APPLY` Considering, however, the first is an `INNER JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`, then it seems like it only makes the query confused, as there's no "benefit".

Comment: How is it possible that the maximum of one row can be greater than the sum of all rows? Btw nulls are treated as zero for the sum anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I've misunderstood what you're asking for (possible, because there are no data examples), I believe this will retrieve what you're looking for. I also took the liberty of changing the way you had done your joins. I saw no reason to have the nesting done that way, and as Larnu pointed out in his comment, it made reading it more difficult than it needed to be.

```
with ArticleLocations as (
    select articleid, sum(currentquantity) as TotalQty
    from ArticleLocations
    group by articleid)

SELECT 
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliveryNumber AS ordernummer,
    Customer.CustomerName AS klantnaam,
    OutgoingDetails.OrderLineDescription AS artikel,
    MAX(OutgoingDetails.Quantity) AS gevraagd,
    SUM(ISNULL(OutgoingSerial.Quantity, 0)) AS gepickt,
    OutgoingDetails.LineNum AS lijnnummer,
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.distributeddate AS pickdatum,
    Article.OrderlineDescription,
    Article.ExternalNumber,
    ArticleLocations.TotalQty
FROM Customer 
INNER JOIN OutgoingSessionDelivery ON Customer.Id = OutgoingSessionDelivery.CustomerId
        AND Customer.Id = OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliverToCustomerId
LEFT OUTER JOIN OutgoingDetails ON OutgoingSessionDelivery.Id = OutgoingDetails.SalesDeliveryId
LEFT OUTER JOIN  OutgoingLocation ON OutgoingDetails.Id = OutgoingLocation.OutgoingDetailsId
LEFT OUTER JOIN OutgoingSerial ON OutgoingLocation.Id = OutgoingSerial.OutgoingLocationId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Article on Article.id = OutgoingDetails.articleid
LEFT OUTER JOIN ArticleLocations on ArticleLocations.articleid = Article.articleid
-- WHERE OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliveryNumber = 12959 
--   AND OutgoingDetails.LineNum = 14
GROUP BY 
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.DeliveryNumber,
    Customer.CustomerName,
    OutgoingDetails.OrderLineDescription,
    OutgoingDetails.LineNum,
    OutgoingSessionDelivery.distributeddate,
    Article.OrderlineDescription,
    Article.ExternalNumber,
    ArticleLocations.TotalQty
HAVING 
    MAX(OutgoingDetails.Quantity) > SUM(ISNULL(OutgoingSerial.Quantity, 0));
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your code. I get this error when I try to execute it:

Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Recursive common table expression 'ArticleLocations' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Is there more code involved that you haven't showed?